# maximum flow algorithm in less than O(n^3)

Tags: performance, graph

I have a problem: given is a graph which contains edges with weights in range 1...K. I have to design an algorithm that calculates the maximum flow and takes less time then O(n^3).
We have an additional hint to use blocking flow with combination of some data structure.

My idea:
to use Dinic's algorithm with dynamic trees -> O(VE logV), but that is still to slow (because for dense graphs E is approximately n^2).

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a variant of [Dinic's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm). The references on the Wikipedia page should get you going.

Good luck!